# Recursive binary search in Java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search

I don't understand why the following piece of code is returning **0**.

Firstly, here is my test:

```
 @Test
public void testOddEntriesMatchRecursive() {
    int[] arr = new int[]{1,3,5};
    ...
    Assert.assertEquals(2, Chopper.chopRecursive(5, arr));
}
```

Next, here is the part of the implementation that matters:

```
static int chopRecursive(int toFind, int[] arr) {

    /* Empty array test */
    if (arr.length == 0) return -1;

    /* Calculate the midpoint */
    int midpoint = (arr.length) / 2;

    if (arr[midpoint] == toFind) {
        return midpoint;
    } else if (arr[midpoint] > toFind) {
        if (midpoint == 1) {
            if (arr[0] == toFind)
                return 0;
            else
                return -1;
        } else {
            return midpoint + chopRecursive(toFind, Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, midpoint));
        }
    } else {
        return midpoint + chopRecursive(toFind, Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, midpoint, (arr.length - 1)));
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the result of my test:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :2
Actual   :0
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: It is wrong because you are resizing the array each time. If you find the occurence at the first time will be correct. But afterwards, what you get is the index relative to that particular subarray. You should work with the original array.

Comment: Although it doesn't solve the problem, note that if you need `Array.copyOf` (linear complexity) you should just use linear search. Just pass the array along the function instead.

Comment: You have missed the last element of the array. copyOfRange is exclusive to you shoudl pass arr.length on the final line not array.length-1

Comment: (Note: Please don't post answers in comments.)

Comment: @NiVeR: I resize the array to find the correct index. The code works, it was the (arr.length - 1) in copyOfRange that was the error. I don't understand how in an array of {1, 3, 5} you can have arr.length = 3 as your "to index". In my mind that is out of bounds.

Comment: @CornelVerster I guess it might work but I don't see the point of doing what you do. Why do you need to copy each time the array of reduced size when you can just use the original one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem might be with the following call:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, midpoint, (arr.length - 1))
```

According to the documentation:

> parameter *to* - the final index of the range to be copied, **exclusive**. (This index may lie outside the array.)

If I change the call to:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, midpoint, arr.length)
```

it returns 2.